# How to read in a single digit for binary calculator c?

Tags: c, scanf

I am doing a basic c programming problem online online.
Basically what I have to do is take in an input(from the console), say

```
00000100+10000001
```

and produce the right output

```
00000011
```

I found an algorithm that i could use to convert binary to decimal and decimal to binary. I don't need help on that part. 
The problem states that you shouldn't use arrays(strings included). What I was thinking was to take user input of one digit at a time and then process each digit. However whenever I use the

```
scanf("%d",&i)
```

, input always advances to a new line which i want to avoid in order for the input and output to match up. Does anyone know how how to take in one digit from the user without moving to the next line?

Comment: Did you check [`getc`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the problem correctly, arrays (and thus strings *as character arrays*) are banned, but character I/O in general probably isn't? If that's the case, you can read in and process one character at a time using `getc()`.

Answer (score 1):

Limit the width of the scan.

```
if (scanf("%1d",&i) != 1) 
  Handle_Failure();  // This is likely the '+' in stdin.
```

Remember that `stdin` is typically line buffered.  No input, into `scanf()`, `getc()`, etc. is seen until the user completes the line.

---

Recommend instead to read the user's line of input and process the buffer.  Process 1 `char` at a time if desired.

```
char buf[1000];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) Handle_IOError_or_EOF();

char *s = buf;
while (*s) {
  Parse_Buffer();
  s++;
}
Do_Stuff();
```

Comment: op indicated no arrays allowed.  so this code example is not acceptable.